# How to get active downloads?

Tags: android, networking, download

Could somebody tell me if it's possible to get if there are some active downloads from network? Android devices contain system application called **Downloads** and I think it should be possible to get if this application contains some active downloads or not. Or is there some better option to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DownloadManager` has a [`query()`](http://goo.gl/Rixnk) method which you can use to

> Query the download manager about downloads that have been requested.

something like this

```
Query query = new Query();
query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING);
```